# Flow Type Generator

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Is there a way to create a type 'generator' in Flow?

In my redux code, I have a middleware that deals with API actions.

```
export const updateUser = (user: User, changes: UserParams) => ({
  user,
  [CALL_API]: {
    types: [
      "UPDATE_USER_REQUEST",
      "UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS",
      "UPDATE_USER_FAILURE",
    ],
    endpoint: `/users/${user.id}`,
    method: "PATCH",
    body: changes,
  },
});
```

Because of how my middleware is defined, I know this means my reducers need to respond to three actions which will look like this:

```
{
  type: "UPDATE_USER_REQUEST",
  user: { id: 1, ... },
}

{
  type: "UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS",
  user: { id: 1, name: 'Ben', ... },
  response: { id: 1, name: 'Bill', ... // API Response Shape }
}

{
  type: "UPDATE_USER_FAILURE",
  user: { id: 1, ... },
  status: 400 // API response code,
  message: { email: 'Is already taken' // API Errors },
}
```

Currently I have to manually enter what these action shapes look like, so that I can type the `action` in my reducer correctly.

Is there a way for me to programatically generate the Action Types for these three actions, if I provide the shape of the success and failure API responses?

E.g.

```
type APISuccessResponseType = {
  user: User
}

type APIErrorResponseType = {
  validationErrors: { [field: string]: string }
}

type UpdateUserActions = GENERATE_API_ACTION_TYPES(typeof updateUser, APISuccessResponse, APIErrorResponse)
```

I don't know how to fill in `GENERATE_API_ACTION_TYPES`, but it should return the following type definition:

```
| {
  type: "UPDATE_USER_REQUEST",
  user: User,
}
| {
  type: "UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS",
  user: User,
  response: APISuccessResponseType,
}
| {
  type: "UPDATE_USER_FAILURE",
  user,
  status: 404 | 500,
  message: APIErrorResponseType,
}
```